# ColdFusion .Net class not found

Tags: .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When running the following code:

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="test" 
       class="GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless" 
       assembly="#expandpath("../GoCardlessSdk.dll")#">
<cfdump var="#test#">
```

I receive the error:

> The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute. Message Class GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless not found in the specified assembly list.

The C# code for the class I am trying to call is show [here](https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-dotnet/blob/master/GoCardlessSdk/GoCardless.cs).

Things I have done:

- Checked that the correct version of .Net (3.5) is installed for the DLL which I am targeting
- Checked that the ColdFusion .Net service is running
- Check the namespace for the class (I think I am doing this bit correctly but would happily be corrected)

I have just tried the following code:

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="proc" class="System.Diagnostics.Process">  
<cfdump var="#proc#">
```

Which did work as expected which at least shows that the .Net service is running.

Any help to get overcome this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I needed to included the supporting DLLs:

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="GoCardless" class="GoCardlessSdk.GoCardless" assembly="#expandpath("../GoCardlessSdk.dll")#,#expandpath("../Newtonsoft.Json.dll")#,#expandpath("../RestSharp.dll")#">
```